# Dynamically building collection to loop over in Airflow dag

Tags: python, airflow

I have been working with Airflow a lot recently and finding a very common pattern is to loop over some collection to create multiple tasks. Very similar to the [example_python_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py) dag found in the example dags folder in github.

My question has to do with dynamically building up the collection the loop is iterating over. Let's say you want to create a task for each of an unknown set of clients stored in a database and you plan to query them as a means to populate your list. Something like this:

```
first_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='some_upstream_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=some_upstream_task,
    dag=dag)

clients = my_database_query()

for client in clients:
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='client_' + str(client),
        python_callable=some_function,
        dag=dag)

    task.set_upstream(first_task)
```

From what I have seen this means that even if your dag only runs weekly your database is being polled every 30 seconds for these clients. Even if you set an upstream operator from the iterator and return the clients via xcoms and replace the `my_database_query()` with an `xcom_pull()` your still polling xcoms every 30 secs. This seems wasteful to me, so I'm wondering if there are any better patterns for this type of dag?

Comment: I think dynamic DAG is a bad practice in Airflow. On each DAG rendering, all previous DAG runs will be changed. You might lose some history/logs + you can accidentally trigger unneeded execution as tasks in old DAG runs will be added in "no state". If you touch such DAG run they will be triggered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672724/airflow-creating-dynamic-tasks-from-xcom This should give you some ideas

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample we don't see the schedule interval of the DAG, but I'm assuming that you have it scheduled let's say `@daily`, and that you want the DB query to run once a day.

In Airflow, the DAG is parsed periodically by the scheduler (hence the "every 30 seconds"). So your python code causes an issue.

In your case, I would consider changing perspective : why not trying to run the database query in a PosgresOperator [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/postgres_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.postgres_operator.PostgresOperator) and then make that part of the DAG ? Based on the output of that Operator (that you can propagate via XCOM for example or via a file in Object Storage) you can then have a PythonOperator downstream that does not run a function for one client but for all of them.

Comment: this seems to intuitive but airflow doesn't support this behavior since xcoms are generated at runtime not at parse time. Hence while those xcoms values would never be available for building dag. File Object will cause the same issue since at the time of parsing File object should be present. I am trying to implement same but it seems to be impossible to do it without having top level python fetching values from database.