# Apache Airflow How to process multiple files in loop

Tags: airflow

Hi I am trying to process multiple files using apache airflow. I tried different options, but ended up using triggerdagrunoperator. So basically i have 2 dags, one is scheduled dag to check the file and it kicks of the trigger dag if file found. but i would like to repeat this for many files. Check one file at a time, if file exist, add parameters and call trigger dag with it.

```py
def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
    task_id = context['params']['task_id']
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    file_type = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_id, key='file_type')
    if file_type is not None and file_type != "":
        dag_run_obj.payload = {'file_type': file_type, 'file_name': file_name, 'file_path': full_path}
        return dag_run_obj
    return None

trigger_dag_run_task = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_dag_run_task',
    trigger_dag_id="trigger_dag",
    python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
    params={'task_id': check_if_file_exists_task_id},
    dag=dag,
)

def execute_check_if_file_exists_task(*args, **kwargs):
    input_file_list = ["a","b"]

    for item in input_file_list:
        full_path = json_data[item]['input_folder_path']
        directory = os.listdir(full_path)
        for files in directory:
            if not re.match(file_name, files):
                continue
            else:
                # true
                kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='file_type', value=item)
                return "trigger_dag_run_task"
        #false
        return "file_not_found_task"

def execute_file_not_found_task(*args, **kwargs):
    logging.info("File Not found path.")

file_not_found_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='file_not_found_task',
    retries=3,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=execute_file_not_found_task,
    op_args=[])

check_if_file_exists_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='check_if_file_exists_task',
    retries=3,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=execute_check_if_file_exists_task,
    op_args=[])

check_if_file_exists_task.set_downstream(trigger_dag_run_task)
check_if_file_exists_task.set_downstream(file_not_found_task)
```

Comment: Can you crop your code so that it's only the part relevant to your question?

Comment: Reduced it. basically i need to loop airflow task for every file. the way i am doing in execute_check_if_file_exists_task

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Airflow - creating dynamic Tasks from XCOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672724/airflow-creating-dynamic-tasks-from-xcom)