# how to pass a Xcom parameter(list) outside of python method?

Tags: python, airflow

I want to create parallel running. For each id in `ids` list create a new `PythonOperator`
how can I pass the `ids` list outside `prepare_parameters` function? or alternatively can I create the `operations` list in `prepare_parameters` call
`prepare_parameters_operator >> operation >> end_tasks`?

```
def prepare_parameters(**context):
  dag_conf = context['dag_run'].conf
  ids = dag_conf['ids'] if 'ids' in dag_conf else [1,2,3]
  context['ti'].xcom_push(key='ids', value=ids)
  

def do_something(id, **context):
  ### do something###


prepare_parameters_operator = PythonOperator(python_callable=prepare_parameters,
                                             task_id='prepare_parameters',
                                             queue='default',
                                             dag=dag)  

operations = []
for id in ids: ### how to get the ids from Xcom? ###
    operations.append(PythonOperator(python_callable=do_something,
                                     task_id='do_something_{}'.format(id),
                                     queue='default',
                                     op_kwargs={'id': id},
                                     dag=dag))

for operation in operations:
    prepare_parameters_operator >> operation >> end_tasks
```

Comment: how/where are you defining `dag_conf` initially?

Comment: first line of ```prepare_parameters``` (edited now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, in Airflow 2.3.0 you can use [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) if you are OK with not having explicit nodes for each `id`. The number of tasks under the "do_something" node can change at runtime based on the output from the "prepare_parameters" task. The number in the square brackets of "do_something" indicates the number of tasks that were mapped.

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@task(queue="default")
def prepare_parameters(dag_run=None):
    return dag_run.conf.get("ids", [1, 2, 3])


@task(queue="default")
def do_something(id):
    print(id)


@dag(start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None)
def prepare_parameters_dag():
    _prepare_parameters_operator = prepare_parameters()
    _do_something = do_something.expand(id=_prepare_parameters_operator)


_ = prepare_parameters_dag()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is *almost* impossible. This answer describing the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556790/2956135).

So, I usually approach this parallel processing like this.

```
# Specify a static number of tasks
WORKERS = 3

def do_something(worker_id, **context):
    dag_conf = context['dag_run'].conf
    ids = dag_conf['ids'] if 'ids' in dag_conf else [1, 2, 3]

    # Find the ids that this worker needs to do something.
    # If worker_id = 1, and ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] then sub_ids = [1, 4]
    sub_ids = [x for x in ids if x % WORKERS == worker_id]

    if len(sub_ids) < 1:
        print('No processes for this worker.')
        return

    # Do something with sub_ids
    for i in sub_ids:
        print('processing...  ', i)
```

Then define DAGs following.

**If Airflow 2.0+**

```
with DAG(...) as dag:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    with TaskGroup(group_id='tasks') as task_group:
        for i in range(WORKERS):
            inner_one = PythonOperator(task_id=f'inner_{i}',
                                       python_callable=do_something,
                                       op_kwargs={'worker_id': i})

    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    start >> task_group >> end
```

**If Airflow < 2.0**

```
with DAG(...) as dag:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    tasks = []
    for i in range(WORKERS):
        tasks.append(PythonOperator(task_id=f'inner_{i}',
                                    python_callable=do_something,
                                    op_kwargs={'worker_id': i}))

    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    start >> tasks >> end
```